# log4j duplicate logging grails

Tags: grails, log4j

I am logging from my grails 1.3.7 application and am seeing essentially duplicate records in the log:

```
12/07/25 23:57:39 TRACE querium.SearchService: setting snippet for posting 1855803974 [null] 54: document 1534340330 [632]
25 Jul 2012 23:57:39,943     7851 TRACE pool-1-thread-1 SearchService:? gene 60258782 - setting snippet for posting 1855803974 [null] 54: document 1534340330 [632]
```

My logging is configured like this:

```
appenders {
    // appender for usage tracking
    appender new org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender(
        name:"usageAppender",
        maxFileSize:"100KB",
        maxBackupIndex: 10000,
        file:"usage.log",   // "/tmp/logs/usage.log",
        layout:pattern(conversionPattern: '%d{DATE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n')
    )
    appender new org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender(
        name:"querium",
        maxFileSize:"1000KB",
        maxBackupIndex: 10000,
        file:"querium.log",   // "/tmp/logs/querium.log",
        layout:pattern(conversionPattern: '%d{DATE} %8X{memoryused} %5p %t %c{1}:%L %X{username} %X{request} - %m%n')
    )
    console name:'stdout', layout:pattern(conversionPattern: '%d{DATE} %8X{memoryused} %5p %t %c{1}:%L %X{username} %X{request} - %m%n')
}
root {
    error 'querium', 'stdout'
}

error  'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet',  //  controllers
       'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages', //  GSP
       'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh', //  layouts
       'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.filter', // URL mapping
       'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping', // URL mapping
       'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons', // core / classloading
       'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins', // plugins
       'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate', // hibernate integration
       'org.springframework',
       'org.hibernate' 

warn  'org.mortbay.log'
debug 'grails.app.service'
trace 'grails.app.service.backgroundservice'
error 'org.hibernate.SQL'
trace 'grails.app.controller.com.fxpal.querium.UiController'
trace 'grails.app.controller.com.fxpal.querium.CommentController'
warn  'grails.app.controller.com.fxpal.querium.TopicController'
off 'grails.app.service.com.fxpal.redis.RedisService'
trace 'grails.app.service.com.fxpal.querium.SearchService'
debug   'com.fxpal.cloudwork.docubrowse.SearchDocubrowse'
off 'grails.app.service.com.fxpal.proxy.ProxyService'

debug 'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.*'
debug 'com.fxpal.querium.CiteSeerDocumentParser'

debug 'com.fxpal.querium.LoggingFilters'
    info 'usageAppender':'usage.gui'
```

The correct data is going to the `usageAppender`. Can someone practiced in this arcana figure out why I am getting doubled records, but slightly different, records for the rest of the logging?

**EDITED 26 JUL 2012**: Added rest of logging configuration.

Comment: Can you reinstate the logger definitions that have been "deleted for clarity"?  I can't see anything in this snippet that would cause the effects you're seeing, but there may be something in the elided section that explains it.  Also, where are you seeing the duplicated messages, on stdout or in querium.log?

Comment: I modified the sample code in the question per your request. I am seeing the doubled-up messages in `catalina.out` in the tomcat log directory. The `querium.log` file is correct, and includes only records that start with the `DD MMM YYYY` format (the second line in my log sample at the top of the question).

Answer (score 1):

The output you are seeing looks like there are two different console appenders attached to your root logger (or possibly one attached to the root logger and another one attached somewhere further down the logger tree).  The second line you're seeing is your own `stdout` logger format but the first line is consistent with a pattern layout of

```
%d{yy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss} %p %c{1}: %m%n
```

which is not the Grails default format.  Checking the code for the Grails log4j DSL parser I notice that it does *not* reset the logging configuration before it starts processing the DSL.  Thus I suspect you have a stray `log4j.properties` or `log4j.xml` file somewhere on your classpath (either in `src/java` or similar, or buried inside one of the JAR files that your app depends on) which is creating this extra appender before the DSL parser runs.  You can determine this in your `BootStrap.init` by doing

```
this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResources("log4j.properties").each {
  println it
}
```

(and likewise for log4j.xml).  If it turns out to be inside a JAR and you can't easily excise it you could try calling `LogManager.loggerRepository.resetConfiguration()` as the very first thing in your `log4j` closure (before your own `appenders` section).

Comment: another way,you can check the logback.groovy to add a additivity="false" to the application logger,such as:logger('db.manager',DEBUG,['STDOUT'],false), refer from: https://logback.qos.ch/manual/groovy.html